# Como usar Jenkins para ver quais arquivos foram modificados no commit?

Tags: mysql, jenkins, gitlab, integração-contínua

Estou trabalhando com PHP e Mysql no Windows, meu repositório esta no GitLab. Eu desejo usar o Jenkins para executar um job ou pipeline quando realizar um push para o repositório.

O job deve checar os arquivos alterados no commit e se houver alterações em algum arquivo no diretório chamado bd_changes ele deve executar o SQL que encontra-se neste arquivo modificado.

Resumindo:

- Para executar o script SQL criarei um Build do tipo "Executar no comando do windows".
- Como faço para identificar se houve alterações em arquivos do diretório bd_changes ?
- Como faço para ler o conteúdo deste arquivo ?

Obs: Sei que é possível utilizar o GitLab para realizar o procedimento e dispensar o Jenkins, mas estou estudando a ferramenta.

Answer (score 0):

> Estou trabalhando com PHP e Mysql no Windows, meu repositório esta no GitLab. Eu desejo usar o Jenkins para executar um job ou pipeline quando realizar um push para o repositório.

Sobre as alterações de push do Gitlab para o Jenkins, você pode criar um webhook. Veja este link:https://imasters.com.br/devsecops/gitlab-jenkins-uma-integracao-poderosa

> Resumindo:
>   Para executar o script SQL criarei um Build do tipo "Executar no comando do windows".

Você pode fazer a integração com o Jenkins, juntamente com o [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) ou o [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) assim, você versiona os scripts de uma forma mais dinâmica.